# PL SQL FUNCTION BODY RETURN SQL QUERY GETS ERROR: ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I get an ORA-20001: Query must begin with SELECT or WITH when I verify the code below. Does that mean I can't use FOR record (sql query) and a loop? Is it ok to load APEX card info the way I did in the loop?  Any help is appreciated.

My goal is to display all media for a project and make the icon turn green for MEDIA that is referenced in a specific STEP_MEDIA row. I have tried outer joins, but I get duplicates. If there is a better way please let me know.

Oracle Cloud
Application Express 21.1.7
Database Version: 19c

```
return q'~

DECLARE
n_count number;
BEGIN
FOR record in (SELECT *
FROM MEDIA
where KHN_PROJECT_ID = :P300_PROJECT_ID
 ORDER BY FILE_NAME)

LOOP 
 CARD_TITLE := record.FILE_NAME;
 CARD_SUBTITLE := record.FILE_MIMETYPE;
CARD_LINK := apex_util.prepare_url( '#' );
       CASE WHEN record.FILE_MIMETYPE LIKE 'video%'
        THEN
      CARD_TEXT :=  '<video> ...</video>';
       ELSE 
      CARD_TEXT := '<img> ...</img>';
      END CASE; 
       
      CARD_ICON := 'fa-check';
      SELECT COUNT(STEP_MEDIA_ID) INTO n_count
      FROM STEP_MEDIA
      WHERE MEDIA_ID = record.MEDIA_ID AND STEP_ID = :P300_STEP_ID_LOADED;
       IF ncount = 0
       THEN 
      CARD_COLOR := 'u-success';
       ELSE
       CARD_COLOR := 'u-normal';
       END IF;
        
CARD_SUBTEXT := '<button class="t-Button t-Button--noLabel t-Button--icon add-favorite" id="fav_'||record.MEDIA_ID||'" type="button">Select</span></button>';
END LOOP;
END;
 
~';
```

Here is the code I wrote using an outer join. It produces duplicate rows.

```
select m.FILE_NAME AS CARD_TITLE,
       m.FILE_MIMETYPE AS CARD_SUBTITLE,
      
       m.MEDIA_ID,
apex_util.prepare_url( '#' ) CARD_LINK,
       CASE WHEN m.FILE_MIMETYPE LIKE 'video%'
        THEN
        '<video >...</video>'
       ELSE 
       '<img >...</img>'
      END 
       CARD_TEXT,
       'fa-check' CARD_ICON,
       CASE WHEN sm.step_media_id is NULL
       THEN 
       'u-success'
       ELSE 
       'u-normal'
       END
        CARD_COLOR,

  from MEDIA m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STEP_MEDIA sm
  ON m.MEDIA_ID = sm.MEDIA_ID
 where m.KHN_PROJECT_ID = :P300_PROJECT_ID OR sm.STEP_ID = :P300_STEP_ID_LOADED
 ORDER BY m.FILE_NAME
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the input and the required output from the query? It's not all that obvious to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Lets say I have 10 media records with media details in them. Lets say I have two steps. In the step_media  table it identifies the the media record(s) associated with a given step. The two steps could have the same media record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query uses sql which is compatible with Oracle Apex and displays all media and shows which media is used in a step. The subquery was the solution.

```
select DISTINCT m.FILE_NAME AS CARD_TITLE,
       m.FILE_MIMETYPE AS CARD_SUBTITLE,
       m.TAGS AS TAGS,
       m.MEDIA_ID,
apex_util.prepare_url( '#' ) CARD_LINK,
       CASE WHEN m.FILE_MIMETYPE LIKE 'video%'
        THEN
        '<video controls width = "100%" height= "100%" class="object-fit">... </video>'
       ELSE 
       '<img >...</img>'
      END 
       CARD_TEXT,
       'fa-check' CARD_ICON,
       CASE WHEN sm.step_media_id is NULL
       THEN 
        'u-normal'
    ELSE 
      'u-success'
       END
        CARD_COLOR,
 '<button class="t-Button t-Button--noLabel t-Button--icon add-favorite" id="fav_'||m.MEDIA_ID||'" type="button">Select</span></button>' CARD_SUBTEXT
  from MEDIA m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * FROM STEP_MEDIA WHERE STEP_ID = :P300_STEP_ID_LOADED) sm
  ON m.MEDIA_ID = sm.MEDIA_ID
 where m.KHN_PROJECT_ID = :P300_PROJECT_ID 
 ORDER BY m.FILE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Apex, right?

Errors with codes from -20000 to -20999 are *user-defined*. In this case, Apex developers created it (so it's not one of *built-in* Oracle errors).

What does it say? Looks like you want to "dynamically" create a Classic report with the Cards layout. You're supposed to return a **valid query**, and it begins with a `select` or the `with` keyword (if you're using a `with` factoring clause, i.e. a CTE (common table expression)).

There's no evidence that code you posted returns what I said.

From my point of view, you shouldn't be doing it in a loop anyway. Everything can be done with a single query (in your case, that would be a `join` of two tables) that uses `CASE` expressions to set certain `CARD_...` values.

That query would then be Classic report's *source*.

Comment: I posted my code using an outer join. It gives me duplicate rows. Not sure how to get the required step_id_loaded into to the case expression for card color.

Comment: When I add the or statemnt to the where clause I get duplicate rows. When I don't add it, the query doesn't take the desired step_media rows into account.

Comment: If they are REALLY duplicates, then use `select DISTINCT ...`

Comment: I added DISTINCT which eliminated the duplicate rows. Now the problem is that for card color all STEP_MEDIA rows are selected instead of the STEP_MEDIA rows that should be selected by sm.STEP_ID = :P300_STEP_ID_LOADED.